# LaTeX throws a missing } error, but I can't see the issue

Tags: errors

Just as the title says, I really don't see how there's a missing brace anywhere. I'm a rookie with LaTeX so I don't know if there's some other cause for this kind of error. I have `amsmath` included for the `align` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\textbf{1.}\\
    \begin{align}
    (a) $f \circle g \circle h =& 2(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}})$\\
    (b) $h \circle g \circle =& \sqrt{\frac{2x}{1+2x}}$\\
    (c) $f \circle f =& 4x$\\
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please can you make your code compilable by adding a preamble?

Comment: `align` uses maths mode already so you don't want `$` signs. But `\circle` can't be used in maths mode. What are you trying to do exactly? You should use `\\` in the first line. And it looks as if you are manually numbering things. Don't do that. People are useless at it. Computers are good at it.

Comment: Well, one problem is that `align` is a math mode environment and automatically sticks you in math mode. `$` signs, by and large, shouldn't appear anywhere within an `align` environment (I can think of the exception of entering text mode and then having maths within that: `... \text{xyz $a + b$ pqr stu}`). In other news I guess you're trying to make a list. This is actually quite a hard list to make, with the alignment as well (personally I'd probably sacrifice that) but you should do a little reading into how to make lists with LaTeX

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner

Comment: I had replaced `\circ` with `\circle` because I initially thought that was an issue. Thanks for the link and for the explanation of align, it makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something vaguely like this?

[image: grouped equations]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{align}
      f \circ g \circ h =& 2\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}}\right)\\
      h \circ g \circ =& \sqrt{\frac{2x}{1+2x}}\\
      f \circ f =& 4x
    \end{align}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I just got this to work in my own document. I take it that `\item` is an indicator for the `enumerate` environment?

Comment: @AlexClough `\item` increments the counter and prints the value (simplistic explanation I think), but yeah it's what causes the number to be there.  But the great thing about it is it also takes care of the numbering. So if you have an (a) and a (b) and then you wanna stick an item in between them, you just put your cursor between them, add in another `\item` put whatever you wanna put and it will automatically renumber everything for you. Same as if you wanna reorder (a) and (b) and then if you ever wanna refer to (a) again, it can do that automatically too

Comment: @AlexClough `\item` indicates an item in a list. The `enumerate` tells LaTeX that the list items should be numbered. If you used the `itemize` environment, the `\item` would get you something like a bullet instead.